# Help With Ubuntu 18.04 setting up Xox 360 Wired Controller

Tags: steam, 18.04, xbox-360

so I've tried Googling this for awhile with 0 success. I tried installing xboxdrv which recognizes the controller but the right analog stick is all messed up and acts as if I am constantly pushing up on it and calibration does absolutely nothing to fix it.

I tried xpad as well which doesn't even cause the controller to work at all. Is there any solution to this?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried to install the following package? sudo apt-get install joystick